# Rails + docker-compose localhostへアクセスができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

dockerを用いてrailsアプリケーションを開発しようとしているところです。

docker-compose run web rails db:migrate
を実行しデータベースが作成されたことまでは確認できましたがlocalhost:3000へアクセスをしたところ、以下のように表示されました。

```
このページは動作していませんlocalhost からデータが送信されませんでした。
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

想定として、railsアプリケーションのデフォルトページが表示されることを期待しております。

どなたかアドバイスをいただけたらと思います。

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgresql'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgresql-pass'
    restart: always
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
```

---

**試したこと**

`http://0.0.0.0:3000` でアクセス　→　変化なし

`http://127.0.0.1:3000` でアクセス　→　変化なし

`docker-compose run web rails s` すでに存在していた

`docker-compose exec web bash` にて仮想環境に入り下記コマンドを打ったところ
標準のHTMLファイルが取得できたため、仮想環境内だと正常に動作しているようです。

```
curl localhost:3000

〜〜〜
 <h1>Yay! You&rsquo;re on Rails!</h1>
〜〜〜
```

Answer (score 1):

swarmクラスタを別で構築しておりそれが邪魔していました。
docker swarm leave --force コマンドでswarmクラスタから抜けて再度docker up -dを実行したところ正常に動作いたしました。